# ZK app. Spring security doesn't return user inside event listener

Tags: spring-security, zk

I have app with ZK and Spring Security. I logged in application through spring security mechanism. On index page I have some components which are created dynamically. "A" component has click listener;

```
***point1**
userComponent = new A("link");
userComponent.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, new EventListener<Event>() {    
    public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {        
        **point2**
        //do something with current user    
    }
});
```

In *point1* I try to get current user with `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` It's work perfect and I receive logged user. But in *point2* `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns null. How to get current user inside on click event?

Maybe stack traces can help. I see no SecurityFilters in stacktrace to *point2*

This is stack trace to *point1* http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=k4EhXrAi 
Stack trace to *point2* http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=v1mbfbwi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have defined an empty filter chain for whatever URL matches the event event handler (I can tell this from the fact that [this line](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.java#L186) is included in your second stack trace). So you are correct - the request is bypassing Spring Security and thus doesn't pick up the current user information. It should be obvious from the debug log since you will see a message along the lines of:

> has an empty filter list *or* has no matching filters

Without seeing your configuration it's hard to say exactly what it is (I don't know anything about zk), but you should easily be able to debug the requests coming from your browser and match them to the debug log output which explains in detail how they are handled.

If you post the configuration and the URL which the Ajax call uses then it should be easier to give an exact answer.

Comment: Yes you're right. I had <http pattern="/zkau/**" security="none"/> instead <intercept-url pattern="/zkau/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" /> /zkau - is servlet for ZK events